# How does JSONAPI translate type/id into navigable URLs?

Tags: rest, json-api, hypermedia

In the [JSONAPI specification, under Resource Objects](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects) it gives this example of a resource:

```
{
  "type": "articles",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "title": "Rails is Omakase"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "author": {
      "links": {
        "self": "/articles/1/relationships/author",
        "related": "/articles/1/author"
      },
      "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
    }
  }
}
```

If I'm NOT using resource inclusion, what should my client be doing with the information contained in:

```
"data": { "type": "people", "id", "9" }
```

The response includes a link to the `article`'s author (`/articles/1/author`) - and I can tell from reading the `data { ... }` element of the response that the author of this article is the person with `id=9`, but I can't actually do anything useful with that information.

It would seem intuitive that I could use this information to make a GET request to `/people/9` to retrieve author details, but that doesn't appear to be part of the JSONAPI spec (although there is a [recommendation](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/) along these lines regarding URLs for resource collections)

Is the inline `type/id` information only relevant in the context of either resource inclusion or cross-referencing with some previously cached response data? Or is there an undocumented convention about translating `type+id` into a resource URL (`GET /{type}/{id}`) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's there for cross-referencing other data retrieved from the server.  You may load the record `person:9` incidentally at some other time, and knowing the `author` relationship on `article:1` would save you the trouble of sending a `GET` to `/articles/1/relationships/author`.

The [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) client-side store, for instance, resolves the reference for you automatically.